# How can i create an .apk application using matlab code?

Tags: android, matlab, apk, application-settings

Is there any possibility of creating a mobile applications (.apk) based on the coding in MATLAB. if there is no option, kindly guide me to create a application of my own in mobile platform.

Comment: You could use python `(kivy + numpy + scipy)` that's probably the closest you'll get to matlab on android/iphone.